# How to know when a line is parallel to the xz-plane

Tags: problem-solving, vectors

What are some features of the equations of a line that is parallel to the xz plane, but does not lie on the plane, and is not parallel to any of the axes?

So far all I got:

-dot product of plane's normal vector and the direction vector of the line must equal zero as the line is perpendicular to the normal vector

-line doesn't lie on plane, meaning one must choose a point that's not on that plane

I just don't know what features are needed to make sure the equation of a line isn't parallel with any of the axes. I feel like it's on the tip of my tongue but I can't quite grasp it.

Any ideas? Also, any other point you may come up with?

Comment: If it's parallel to one axis, it's perpendicular to the other. Is that an easier condition to work with?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the situation. Like I mentioned above, the equation of a line cannot be parallel to any axes.

Comment: You're mistaking me. I mean: If it's parallel to _any_ of the axes, it's necessarily perpendicular to the others. So all you need to check is that it's not perpendicular to any of the axes.

Comment: Oh, okay I see what you mean. Yeah that works. So if the cross product of a direction vector of a line and axis (ex. [0,0,1]) doesn't equate to 0, I can be sure that it's not perpendicular, correct?

Comment: The dot product was what I was getting at, actually (though the cross product will work as well.)

Answer (score 1):

Every line parallel to the xz axis has the form $r(t) = (x_0,y_0,z_0) + (a,0,c)t$. Note that, $\vec{v}\cdot \vec{j} = (a,0,c)\cdot (0,1,0) = 0$. Ie, the vector $j$ is orthogonal director vector $r$. Therefore, $r$ is parallel to the $xz$ plane.